# How do I expand commands within a bash alias?

Tags: git, bash, alias

I'd like to create an alias that runs `git pull origin <current branch name>`

I can get the current branch name with `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.

But how do I put that 2nd command within the first in a bash alias?

I've tried

```
alias gup="git pull origin `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`"
```

and

```
alias gup="git pull origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

but both result in the initial branch name in the alias, not the branch name at the time the command is run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the command substations are expanded inside the double quotes when the alias is *defined*. Using single quotes will fix that by deferring the command substitution until you actually *use* the alias.

```
alias gup='git pull origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)'
```

However, you can save yourself the trouble of trying to get the quoting just right by using a shell function instead.

```
gup () {
    git pull origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
}
```